# Check if record exist

Tags: mysql, insert

I have CSV files and I need to do something like this before inserting data in my table:

```
table fields
id = primary id and auto-increment
house_no
city_code
prv_code
cty_code


if (house_no,city_code,prv_code,cty_code) exists = ignore insert
else if (house_no,city_code,prv_code,cty_code) is null = ignore insert
else (house_no,city_code,prv_code,cty_code) !exist = insert
```

My original code just re-inserts the same values because the primary key **id** is just creating a new id for it and as a result I have duplicates.

I need to do this to avoid duplicates. I tried `INSERT IGNORE` and `REPLACE` but I need a unique key and all fields may have a value which is the same (like they may have different `house_no` but the same `prv_code` or `cty_code` or something like that). I just want to check if the record exist before I insert it.

Comment: I am not sure If I understood you properly, but why don't you use `TRIGGER` for that. However, you provided scarce amount of information.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a unique key over more than one column. In your case you need an unique key containing of the four columns `house_no`, `city_code`, `prv_code` and `cty_code`.

In your case:

```
ALTER TABLE fields
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_fieldsUnique UNIQUE (house_no,city_code,prv_code, cty_code);
```

Answer (score 0):

Load data from CSV-file into second table, and then use INSERT like this to add rows -

```
INSERT INTO t1(id, house_no, city_code, prv_code, cty_code)
  SELECT NULL, t2.house_no, t2.city_code, t2.prv_code, t2.cty_code FROM t2
    LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.house_no = t2.house_no AND t1.city_code = t2.city_code AND t1.prv_code = t2.prv_code AND  t1.cty_code = t2.cty_code
      WHERE t1.id IS NULL
```

(rename table names)